# After Deploying to Heroku data-toggle="popover" requires refresh of page to work?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

Originally I fixed this issue on localhost using the jquery-turbolinks gem but after deploying to Heroku it no longer works! I still must refresh the page in order to use the popover function. Any thoughts?

I require the gem in the production section of my gemfile to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

**Turbolinking** usually needs to force the `ready` function on `page:load`.

**Javascript (+Jquery)**

```
ready = function(){ $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); };
$(document).ready(ready); 
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: Thank You for the post. I was able to solve the problem by explicitly adding a script to enable the popover in the view but thank you for your contribution.